# Creating a document library from custom template with Folder structure inside using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, csom

How can one create a document library from custom library template with Folder structure inside using CSOM?

I have created my template and when creating an instance of that manually folders are created. The challenge is when doing it programatically the folder structure doesn't show.

This is what I have thus far:

```
var listTemplate = clientContext.Site.GetCustomListTemplates(clientContext.Site.RootWeb).GetByName("Test");

clientContext.Load(listTemplate, lt=> lt.Name, lt => lt.FeatureId, lt => lt.ListTemplateTypeKind);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

listCreationInfo.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;
listCreationInfo.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;

List newList = oWeb.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);
newList.EnableFolderCreation = true;
newList.ContentTypesEnabled = true;

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the custom library template include content, and then using the code below to create new library base on the custom library template.

```
string siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lz";
var login = "lz@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "xx";

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

var listTemplate = clientContext.Site.GetCustomListTemplates(clientContext.Site.RootWeb).GetByName("Test");

clientContext.Load(listTemplate, lt => lt.Name, lt => lt.FeatureId, lt => lt.ListTemplateTypeKind);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

ListCreationInformation listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
listCreationInfo.Title = "NewTestLibrary";
listCreationInfo.ListTemplate = listTemplate;
List newList = clientContext.Web.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);

newList.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
newList.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: If my reply help you, please mark the reply as answer, thanks.